# How do I do this in Entity Framework (multiple where's or Join)?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have 2 tables that have a relation ship to each other

Table A has 1 to many relationship with table B, so this creates a navigation property into each.

Now I need to check a value from Table A (userName) and I need to check a value from table B (ClubId).

So in my mind it would be something like

```
Join the tables together
Where A.userName == "bob" &&
where B.clubId == "Car"

// return the count.
```

but now I know with Entity stuff it should make joins less common so I am wondering if I can do it with a join then.

I tried this

```
int count = Entity.TableA.where(a => a.userName == "bob" && a.TableB.where(i => i.ClubId == "Car")).Count();
```

so this does not work since it won't return the right type(the 2nd where). This is just how I thought along the lines how I would expect it to be done would work.

So how should it look?

P.S

I rather have an example done in the Linq method queries like I did above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filtering `TableA` before your join is probably more efficient:

```
var clubs = from a in Entity.TableA
            where a.userName == "bob"
            from b in a.TableB
            where b.clubId == "Car"
            select b;

var count = clubs.Count();
```

You don't have to use two variables, it's just my preference here for clarity.

Or in method syntax you can simplify a bit:

```
var count = Entity.TableA.Where(a => a.userName == "bob")
                         .SelectMany(a => a.TableB)
                         .Count(b => b.clubId == "Car");
```

However, I'm not certain EF understands those particular expressions. If not, the compiler would translate the above query like this:

```
var count = Entity.TableA.Where(a => a.userName == "bob")
                         .SelectMany(a => a.TableB, (a,b) => new { a, b })
                         .Where(x => x.b.clubId == "Car")
                         .Count();
```

Comment: Ah.

Wow. I am not sure what I like better int his case. That selectMany throws me off. So what happens if I needed another filter? would I add another selectMany?

Well the first method syntax works I don't know if it goes down internally and does the second thing. All the queries would take the same execution time.

What is in the second one SelectMany one does. like what is a=> a.TableB, (a,b) =>)  do?

Comment: I've updated the post with a fix in the query translation.

The first SelectMany essentially "flattens" your nested collection, returning a sequence of all B's from all A's. The second SelectMany accepts two delegates, a "collectionSelector" to retrieve the collection of B's from an A and a "resultSelector" to specify the return value given an A and B. LINQ just selects both input objects, for use in the rest of your query.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your EF model has the relationship between Users and Clubs could do something like this:

```
var usersNamedBobInCarClub = 
             from A in User
             from B in A.Clubs
             where A.userName == "bob" &&
                   B.clubId == "Car"
             select A;
```

If you want return elements of both Users and Clubs have a look at joins within the query.

Comment: I will try that but how do I do that in Linq method queries?